# Deleting data in a sql server table takes much time

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a table which has more than 380 million records. I have a stored procedure which:

1. Deletes some records.
2. Insert something.

The total procedure takes around 30  minutes to execute. Out of this `DELETE` takes 28 minutes.

Delete is a simple statement, something along these lines:

```
Delete a where condition_1 AND condition_2 AND condition_3
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Any delete triggers on the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly have a look at your [indexing](http://odetocode.com/Articles/70.aspx) and query..it should really in the first place not take `28 mins` ?

It maybe worth taking a look at [database tuning](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/sql-server-2005/sql-server-database-tuning-advisor.html) and [query optimization](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/john_charles/QueryoptimizationinSQLServer200512112007154303PM/QueryoptimizationinSQLServer2005.aspx)...maybe you can also try to delete records incrementally..something suggested [here](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2008/04/how-to-delete-records-from-large-table.html)..

Comment: Hi Misnomer, Can you please tell me how this ioncremental approach is useful..compared to the one-time one ?...Please see my post regarding this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893216/incremental-delete-how-it-is-beneficial

Answer (score 8):

How is your table organized? what clustered index you have and what non-clustered indexes you have? And what exactly are the 3 conditions?

A DELETE behaves much like a SELECT in that it needs to *find* the rows that qualify for deletion. To do so, it will use the same techniques a SELECT would, and if your condition_1, condition_2 and condition_3 don't have a covering index, they will trigger a table scan which is going to be timed by the size of data (380M).

Answer (score 2):

Are the conditions too large ?
Maybe using index could help to delete faster.

Or, you may use truncate instead of delete.

```
CREATE [UNIQUE] INDEX indexName
ON table
(fieldName [ASC/DESC], ...)
```

The option ASC/DESC can define an order

Comment: The condition is not larger ...just comparing EX: c_number = '01102'. I can not truncate...because I am not deleting the entire data in thisn table.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to index the fields in the condition.  If you create a view of the rows you want deleted, how long does it take?  If you can speed up a view, you can speed up the delete.